# Error al intentar acceder a una lista anidada

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema al intentar acceder a los elementos de una lista anidada.

Tengo estos datos de entrada:

```
string = list("Wizard")
string2 = list("Magical")
lista = [string, string2]
```

Y tengo este código:

```
for a in range(0, len(lista)):
    for b in range(0, len(lista[a])):
        if b % 2 == 0:
            print(lista[a[b]])
```

Como pueden ver, mi idea es imprimir los caracteres de lista[a[b]] siguiendo la siguiente condición: Si el índice de lista[a[b]] es par, imprima el contenido de lista[a[b]]. Sin embargo, me este error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.`. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Que error te tira? Sería útil si proporcionaras información del error , idealmente envía el stacktrace completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejecutando el codigo veo que el error que te aparece es una excepción `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

El problema que tienes en el codigo es que estás intentando indexar `a[b]` siendo que `a` corresponde a un `int` del iterador `range`. La sintaxis correcta para indexar una lista de listas sería, en este caso, `lista[a][b]`. Por lo tanto, la solución correcta debería ser:

```
for a in range(0, len(lista)):
    for b in range(0, len(lista[a])):
        if b % 2 == 0:
            print(lista[a][b])
```